# Drupal session_name()

Tags: php, drupal, session, sessionid

I have a simple and probably stupid question, but I can't really find any good answers. In drupal, when I use `session_name()`, is that unique for every PC? or is the `session_name` a global identifier for the drupal website itself?

Comment: `session_name()` is actually a PHP function - it is not unique to Drupal - just an FYI.

Comment: Yes I know, but all the session functionality in php is overwritable, and In drupal alot of functionality is extenden. Like sess_read, sess_write etc. So it is possible drupal overrides/extends the generation of the session name.

Comment: *all the session functionality in php is overwritable* I don't think you are correct on this part. Yes, I agree, Drupal may call `session_name` somewhere in its code base to assign a name to the session. You can figure this out pretty quickly by taking a look at the session cookie in your browser.

Comment: True, not ALL of it is overwritable and I know what mys session name is, I need to know if it will be the same everywhere. The setup is pretty hard So I can't easily push this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal session name depends on cookie settings (domain and ssl), it is not "unique for every pc".

Take a look here (for drupal 6) :  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/conf_init/6

Comment: So, are you saying that session_name() is the same on every pc and browser for the same drupal website ?

Comment: Ok, Is there any way an anonymous user carries a permanent session id, like any other normal framework does, because drupal seems to create a new session id for every call for anonymous users

Comment: No, drupal will not create a new session id

Comment: take a look here (for drupal 7) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_settings_initialize/7